# What is a good formula for calculating if a LatLong is within a radius (in miles) of a second LatLong?

Tags: geoprocessing

If I have two LatLongs, what is the best way to determine if the first one is within a 10 mile radius of the second?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-do-i-find-the-distance-between-two-coordinates

Comment: Voting to close as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following thread provides algorithms for calculating distance between lat/long coordinate pairs.
[Finding distance between two coordinates in ellipsoid?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-do-i-find-the-distance-between-two-coordinates)

After that, just do a conditional, like: if (distance <= 10):