# Looking for a pythonic way to calculate the length of a WKT linestring

Tags: python, well-known-text, wgs84, srid, length

I was quite unsatisfied with [Calculating Length of Linestrings in WGS84 in Miles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/598/calculating-length-of-linestrings-in-wgs84-in-miles). It kept me wondering if there is a more convenient, Pythonic way to calculate the length of a WKT linestring according to a given SRID.

I have in mind something like:

```
srid="WGS84"
line="LINESTRING(3.0 4.0, 3.1 4.1)"
print length(line, srid)
```

I'm looking for an accurate answer, not `sin\cos` approximations.

Any ideas?

Comment: tomkralidis,
this is a GIS website. your answer ignores that the this is a distance between geospatial coordinates (look up SRID). shapely in of itself cannot compute geospatial distances as it has no knowledge of map projection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [geopy](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/wiki/GettingStarted) module provides the [Vincenty formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html), which provides accurate ellipsoid distances. Couple this with the `wkt` loading in Shapely, and you have reasonably simple code:

```
from geopy import distance
from shapely.wkt import loads

line_wkt="LINESTRING(3.0 4.0, 3.1 4.1)"

# a number of other elipsoids are supported
distance.VincentyDistance.ELLIPSOID = 'WGS-84'
d = distance.distance

line = loads(line_wkt)

# convert the coordinates to xy array elements, compute the distance
dist = d(line.xy[0], line.xy[1])

print dist.meters
```

Comment: +1, would have +10 if I could. Saved my team hours of programming.

Comment: Is this approach any different from @tomkralidis answer if the input coordinates are in WGS-84 already?

Comment: @LarsVegas yes, Shapely only handles planar coordinates -- so it will measure distances accurately in projected space, but not geographic (e.g. WGS-1984).

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Shapely's [length](http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.0/manual.html#length) property, i.e.:

```
from shapely.wkt import loads

l=loads('LINESTRING(3.0 4.0, 3.1 4.1)')
print l.length
```

Comment: Note that the length for this particular example will be meaningless, as it is a geographic coordinate system (WGS84).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) to do it directly but if you really must use Python then there are [Python bindings](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) to let you do it.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but with a hopefully useful contribution. Building on [scw's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/4040/19627) using geopy, I wrote a small function that does the calculation for a shapely LineString object with arbitrarily many coordinates. It uses a [`pairs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257413/1257446#1257446) iterator from Stackoverflow.

Main feature: the docstrings are much longer than the snippets.

```
def line_length(line):
    """Calculate length of a line in meters, given in geographic coordinates.
    Args:
        line: a shapely LineString object with WGS 84 coordinates
    Returns:
        Length of line in meters
    """
    # Swap shapely (lonlat) to geopy (latlon) points
    latlon = lambda lonlat: (lonlat[1], lonlat[0])
    total_length = sum(distance(latlon(a), latlon(b)).meters
                       for (a, b) in pairs(line.coords))
    return round(total_length, 0)


def pairs(lst):
    """Iterate over a list in overlapping pairs without wrap-around.

    Args:
        lst: an iterable/list

    Returns:
        Yields a pair of consecutive elements (lst[k], lst[k+1]) of lst. Last 
        call yields the last two elements.

    Example:
        lst = [4, 7, 11, 2]
        pairs(lst) yields (4, 7), (7, 11), (11, 2)

    Source:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257413/1257446#1257446
    """
    i = iter(lst)
    prev = i.next()
    for item in i:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item
```

Comment: This is wrong: geopy.distance.distance accepts coordinates in (y, x) but a shapely linestring is "an ordered sequence of 2 or more (x, y[, z]) " so geopy's helper function lonlat() must be used.

Comment: @MartinBurch: ouch, you are right. The nasty thing is not even the `[, z]`, but the argument swap `(y, x)` to `(x, y)` that is necessary. Thanks for spotting it. Can you eyeball whether this edit looks less bug-ridden?

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by @ojdo is very nice and it works.

Another way is to do a lat, lon conversion to UTM e.g. using https://gist.github.com/twpayne/4409500.
And then the distance is immediate.