# Intermediate points on a small circle

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, intersection, circle

I need to interpolate lat/lon points along a [small circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmallCircle.html), with a given centre and radius.  I've successfully used [these formulas](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Intermediate) for great circles.  What is the equivalent for small circles?

Comment: How much accuracy do you need?  How small is "small"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the answers to this question - [Calculating Lat/Lng X miles from point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-lat-lng-x-miles-from-point). Using one of the formulas for calculating location from bearing and distance, with a fixed distance and varying bearings, will give you the points of your small circle.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! [Here is a related question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/14909/4251) if you're interested.