# Get nearest feature points from memory

Tags: geotools, jts-topology-suite

I have a set of features (a few hundreds, can grow to a couple of thousands), which have a latitude and longitude. They are not stored in a database because they change frequently (another system is keeping track of them and feeding them to systems including the one in question).

I want to just keep them in memory because the information is very volatile (the objects will be moving on the map).

What is the best Java API I can use to query the closest `N` features of a certain type to a specific point?

I was looking at either JTS or GeoTools (which uses JTS under the hood), but couldn't find any examples of *"find the nearest N features"* (maybe I was looking at the wrong thing or searched with the wrong keywords).

JTS seems to have a `KDTree` that I gather is an efficient data structure for what I need? But no idea how to go from there.

The answer to [Finding N nearest points to point using JTS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158635) seems to indicate that more work is needed to do it, but there surely must be a way to do it from the APIs available that I am just missing, because this is such a common requirement (closest restaurants, closest ATMs etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While JTS does have a [KdTree](http://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/index/kdtree/KdTree.html) implementation, which is the most efficient spatial index for points, that class does not yet have a nearest-neighbours capability.

The [STRtree](http://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/index/strtree/STRtree.html) class does have a [k-nearest-neighbours method](http://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/index/strtree/STRtree.html#nearestNeighbour-org.locationtech.jts.geom.Envelope-java.lang.Object-org.locationtech.jts.index.strtree.ItemDistance-int-), but unfortunately that implementation is not dynamic, so may not work for your use case.

So you may have to use the approach given in [Finding N nearest points to point using JTS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158635).

Keep in mind the caveat about geodetic distance vs planar distance.  If geodetic distance is required you may need a [more sophisticated algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954503/efficient-geodesic-nearest-neighbors).

Comment: I do have a function (I had ported it from JS that I found somewhere on a question here) that calculates distance using the earth radius etc. (I think it assumes the Earth is a sphere) so I think that is not a problem. Assuming that is available, can you update your answer with the right steps (just pseudo code) to find the nearest features of interest from a KDTree? Otherwise what if I built the STRtree from scratch from the data I have available each time I have a new query would that be a bad idea? (I have only a few thousand features of interest)

Comment: You can use the same approach as in [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158635] but use a KDtree.  As for rebuilding a tree on each query, that is going to be slower than simply iterating over all data items.