# Caculating Longitude and Latitude for Moving Object

Tags: latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating Lat/Lng X miles from point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-lat-lng-x-miles-from-point)

I don't know how to ask the question, so I'll explain my requirments -- I hope I'm in the right site :)

- Let's assume that a person is standing somewhere on Earth and his coordinates are: x long, y lat.
- Let's assume that if the person is facing north he is on 0°, south is 180°, north-west is 315° ... etc. (unless there is some standard that I'm not aware of)
- Let's assume that the person can walk in a straight line from his position on the direction he's facing until he completes a full round around the Globe; i.e. return to his starting position.

My question is, what is the equation/set of equations to be used to calculate the person's coordinates (longitude and latitude) every 50, 100, 300 ... etc. kilometers until a full round is done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html see Destination point given distance and bearing from start point

Comment: It looks like an answer to your question is already available here at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-lat-lng-x-miles-from-point.