# Calculate Point C using distance and bearing from points A and B?

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating Lat/Lng X miles from point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-lat-lng-x-miles-from-point)

I'm from old school so have not done math for ages. So I need some help to solve this problem, please :)

I have two points such as A(Lat1, Long1) and B(Lat2, Long2) on the globe. Therefore we can find the bearing and distance etc. Now I want to find the latitude and longitude of a point C which is 100 meters away from point B (on the same protraction).

Any clear help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: It seems you are asking the equivalent of the question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-lat-lng-x-miles-from-point.  Does this solve it for you?