# Translate geographical coordinate

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, coordinates, latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating Lat/Lng X miles from point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-lat-lng-x-miles-from-point)

I would like to know how could I translate a geographical coordinate to an specific distance. So for example let's suppose I'm facing North at (-78.4437,-0.31399). I need to know the coordinate that's 100m farther and has +30 degrees offset from North.
Thanks a lot.