# Calculate the next coordinate from given starting point and distance

Tags: distance, wgs84

On the answer to [Calculating Latitude/Longitude X miles from point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-latitude-longitude-x-miles-from-point?newreg=f922009a39d148bdb8da76a178f31514) what is the tc value?

```
lat = asin( sin(lat1)*cos(d)+cos(lat1)*sin(d)*cos(tc) )
dlon = atan2( sin(tc)*sin(d)*cos(lat1),cos(d)-sin(lat1)*sin(lat) )
lon = mod( lon1-dlon+pi,2*pi )-pi
```

Comment: Is it not the bearing? http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51816.html

Comment: Yes, it is bearing. That is, true course. You can access more detail on that link http://www.askacfi.com/86/true-course-magnetic-course-magnetic-heading-compass-headinghelp.htm

Answer (score 2):

*tc* stands for *True Course*.

The term *True Course* is used in navigation to express the bearing in which the ship is traveling. It is used to differentiate that measured from the geographic north with respect to those measured from the magnetic north.

In your formula, it represents the bearing of the distance (arc lenght) *d* at the starting point (the angle at the vertex of the spherical triangle formed by the starting point, the end point and a pole). Because *d* is the distance measured over a great circle, and over a great circle the *True Course* varies depending on the latitude, so that `sin(tc)*cos(lat)=constant`.