# Does anyone know of an explicit formula that I can plug-n-chug with to convert WGS84 lat lon to kilometers or miles?

Tags: latitude-longitude

I have a lot of lat lon coordinates in WGS84 format and I'm trying to get those into kilometers so that I'm able to calculate distance.

Comment: also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3945/distance-between-lat-long-points?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you have them in a delimited text file you can bring them into a GIS program like ArcMap or QGIS, then export them out to a projected coordinate system.  If you have them in a spreadsheet ArcMap can read Excel files directly, for QGIS you'll need to save the file as a delimited text file.

Comment: I have ArcMap, but I'm very unfamiliar with it. Could you tell me which coordinate system I should export it to to have the lat lon in kilometers?

Comment: What part of the world is your data from? You can start with page 7 of this [projected_coordinate_systems.pdf](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003r/pdf/projected_coordinate_systems.pdf) and find your area of the world. Or research what others are using (e.g UTM, State Plane, Albers, etc.). Also, see the ArcGIS Desktop help topic [Projection basics for GIS professionals](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Projection_basics_for_GIS_professionals/003r00000002000000/) for more info on coordinate systems.

Comment: As ccn said, find out which coordinate system works for your part of the world.  Your best bet will probably be which ever UTM zone applies for the part of the world your data covers, that will give you the coordinates in meters.